# is 480x800 the same as 800x480?

Tags: android, screen

Can resolutions be expressed interchangeably like this?
The documentation seems to sometimes write the bigger number first and sometimes not.
If they're not the same thing, how do I know if I'm getting the height in portrait mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you always read the value as "Width x Height".

So, 480 x 800 means your screen is 480px large and 800px high (Width < Height = portrait) and 800 x 480 means your screen is 800px large and 480px high (Width > Height = landscape).

If it helps, try visualizing the screen as if you were holding it in your hand.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not technically the same.  The default orientation of your phone, portrait mode would be the small x larger.

Though, when you turn your phone to Landscape the numbers change.  Make sense?